# Обработка нажатия кнопки без перезагрузки страницы

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, post

Есть div, внутри поля, кнопка лежит - все это в отдельном файле html(*)

Есть кнопка, уже на index.html, по нажатию на которую я выполняю:
`$.get` как раз тот отдельный файл(*) html - те при нажатии (как бы ajax но мне ответ не нужен, поэтому использую get) просто выплывает окно(div), где пользователь нажимает на кнопку ииии....

Вот тут, при попытке повесить обработчик `click` на кнопку появляется проблема, т.к. элемента этого изначально нет в DOM, те и `id` кнопки(с div'ом который подгружается) и я не могу обработать данные.

Есть выход их этой ситуации? или у меня крайне не правильный подход? Ну те, я хочу отработать логику php без перезагрузки страницы. Только HTML JQ.

Если бы обработчик на вновь появившуюся(подгруженную кнопку) вешался я бы там написал:

```
 $.post('./includes/delrow.php',
       {'idslist[]': ids},
       function(data) {
            alert(data);
            location.reload();
       }
  );
```

Но проблема в том что

```
$('#new_btn').click(function() { ... }
```

Не отрабатывает, тк изначально ее нет в DOM она после выполнения `$.get` появляется.
Заранее благодарен за ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Для этого есть [.on](https://api.jquery.com/on/), [пример](http://jsfiddle.net/Stasonix/EQN86/):

```
<div id="test">Example:</div>

$('#test').on('click','.ap',function(){

    $(this).text('test');

});

$('#test').append('<span class="ap">*</span>');
```

Нажав на `*` будет обновлен текст спана.

Answer (score 1):

замени

```
$('#new_btn').click(function() { ... }
```

на

```
$('body').on('click', '#new_btn', function() { ... }
```

и всё будет работать ;)